# How can i save selected date to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date, gridview

I have a calender which the users will select the date and it must be stored to the database. Please help me get to save the date to the database

Date datatype from the database is "date".

I am getting an error on the date "Input string was not in a correct format."

The date am trying to Insert from the calender   4/11/2015

here is my coding

Class code

```
public Boolean InsertBookings(int BookingID, DateTime Date, DateTime Returndate, int ReturntimeID, string Returnpickupaddress, string Returndropofdetails, string Comments)
    {

        OConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
        oCommand.Connection = OConnection;

        oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oCommand.CommandText = "SP_INSERT_BOOKINGS";
        oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterID", (int)SQLparameters.Insert);
        oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingID", BookingID);
        oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
        oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Returndate", Returndate);
        oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RetuntimeID", ReturntimeID);
        oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Returnpickupaddress", Returnpickupaddress);
        oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Returndropofdetails", Returndropofdetails);
        oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", Comments);

        OConnection.Open();
        Boolean _Results = Convert.ToBoolean(oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());
        OConnection.Close();
        return _Results;

    }
```

Calender code

```
protected void BookingCalendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDate.Text = BookingCalendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
    BookingCalendar1.Visible = false;
}
```

Saving button

```
protected void btnbookings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                bool _var = _booking.InsertBookings(_BooingID,
                Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text.ToString()),
                Convert.ToDateTime(txtReturndate.Text.ToString()),
                int.Parse(cboReturntime.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                txtReturnpickupaddress.Text,
                txtReturndropofdetails.Text,
                txtComments.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just try formatting the date value for entry into the database as an ISO-8601 string e.g. yyyy-MM-dd.

With the DateTime object you can use Date.UtcNow.ToString("o")

Comment: I only need date with no time

Comment: The date am trying to Insert from the calender   4/11/2015

Comment: Right, but it's a DateTime object though? And it's representing the correct date you wish to enter? So you can change how it's output...

Comment: if i understand it correctly, i have changed this format to "MM/dd/yyyy" and still no results..please help

Comment: Almost, but at the point in which you are sending the date into the database, the format should be 'yyyy-MM-dd' e.g. oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

Comment: and from my main button to i have to make changes? or how must it look?

Comment: Nope, you shouldn't need to change anything on the calendar control or the main button as long as the correct DateTime object is being passed into the method where you are saving it to the database. Format the date(s) when you add them to as sql parameters.

Comment: it is still complaining with fomat

 Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text.ToString()),  
        Convert.ToDateTime(txtReturndate.Text.ToString()),

Comment: Are you working with the calendar date object or a string version of it? e.g. BookingCalendar1.SelectedDate - that's the bit you want to pass into database and format it like BookingCalendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: i must put this under save button? am working with a calender date object,where the user click the calender image and it opens and you select the date ....Can you please put in proper coding so that i understand it better and be able to mark it ?

Comment: Possibly, you need to put it at the point where you are sending information to the database. I assume the the Save button triggers a click event (if you using WebForms) which then calls this method InsertBookings(int BookingID,DateTime Date, DateTime Returndate, int ReturntimeID, string Returnpickupaddress,string Returndropofdetails, string Comments) pass the BookingCalendar1.SelectedDate into that method as a parameter...

Comment: am lost here now..how can i upload my project so that you can see or share it with you. Skype,email etc........please!

Comment: Add it to Dropbox and send me a link...?

Comment: owk let me do it in that way...How must  must i post the link here?

Comment: how will i post the link ?

Comment: please give me your email address

Answer (score 0):

You can change your date column data type to varchar(4) to get rid of this error, BUT this is not a solution to your problem. for having accurate answer please post a sample date that you are trying to insert into table.

Comment: I am still facing the same problem of value being one. i did specify  DataTextField nad DataVlaue field

Comment: open new thread and send your code there to resolve it(share its link with me). If your problem with Date is resolved then mark the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Make both the data types as `DATETIME`.In database in your insert query use `CONVERT(DATE,@YourDateTime)` if neede

Comment: am using procedure to insert

Comment: i meant,convert the datetime to Date and then insert